# Why isn't this Angular variable binding?

Tags: angularjs

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong that the value of revisedprice isn't displaying in the span?

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
<strong><span ng-bind-html="revisedprice"></span></strong>
</div>
```

Angular:

```
var app = angular.module('app',[]);

app.controller('ctrl', function($scope, $sce) {
    $scope.revisedprice = "<strike>$17</strike>";
    )};
```

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/wdf6vkck/2/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

seems like you didnt add the [ng-sanitize](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.8/angular-sanitize.js) js and the dependency.

```
var app = angular.module('app',['ngSanitize']);
```

here is the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0pmnLx4L/)

---

if you use `$sce` you controller should be like,

```
app.controller('ctrl', function($scope, $sce) {
    $scope.revisedprice = $sce.trustAsHtml("<strike>$17</strike>"); // add trustAsHtml()
});
```

here is the Demo [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/o5k1zrpa/)

Comment: I'm using $sce but left it out.  I've updated the code.